# help conversion code in prototype to jquery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

Good day, I'm done with the following code into prototype

```
var DataAjax = new Ajax.Updater('Data','/inc/infoPanel.asp', {method:'get', parameters:'Name='+appIdOrName});
        DataAjax.onComplete = function(){
        if ($('Data').innerHTML.indexOf('status=ok')>-1){
            loadBlogsphere(IdOrName);
        }
```

I wonder how would this code in jquery, I'm trying here but I can not.

I thank anyone who can help.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the jQuery's load() method...

[.load() - Description: Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (from jQuery Docs)

```
$('#Data').load('/inc/infoPanel.asp', { Name : appIdOrName }, function(responseData)
{
    // Not sure about this part...
    if (responseData.indexOf('status=ok') > -1)
    {
        loadBlogsphere(IdOrName);
    }
});
```